# fail in crop and capture the image in android

Tags: android, android-image

I tried the code of this [ttl](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/capture-and-crop-an-image-with-the-device-camera--mobile-11458).
When I run it, it captures an image but it doesn't open the crop apps of my phone to crop the image. 
Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library, it should work fine
https://github.com/jdamcd/android-crop

Answer (score 0):

A simple library that can be integrated to your project to achieve this.PhotoCrop can be used to crop images in Android similar to Facebook and Telegram. PhotoCrop is available at

https://github.com/albinmathew/PhotoCrop

Comment: thanks for your help
but how can I solve the 
import com.albinmathew.photocrop.cropoverlay.CropOverlayView; error ? where is cropoverlay class?  http://stackoverflow.com/users/4948375/albin-mathew

Comment: How do you use the library? Is it by gradle compile ?

Comment: add Gradle path to your project if you are using Android Studio, and in eclipse download the project and add it as a library

Answer (score 0):

Try to crop the image by yourself instead of passing it to another crop application. I myself use [this](https://github.com/IsseiAoki/SimpleCropView) simple crop and rotate library, use it